# Android Fatal Exception AsyncTask #3

Tags: android, file, android-asynctask

I have a problem with my app it keeps giving me Fatal Exception AsyncTask #3 when trying to send some data to web server.

If i send the data with no file, the error shows and kills the app, but if i send the data with a file (jpg,mp4) everything works great.

This is the log:

```
10-25 00:31:59.274: E/AndroidRuntime(24895): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #3
10-25 00:31:59.274: E/AndroidRuntime(24895): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
10-25 00:31:59.274: E/AndroidRuntime(24895):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:278)
10-25 00:31:59.274: E/AndroidRuntime(24895):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
10-25 00:31:59.274: E/AndroidRuntime(24895):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
10-25 00:31:59.274: E/AndroidRuntime(24895):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
10-25 00:31:59.274: E/AndroidRuntime(24895):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
10-25 00:31:59.274: E/AndroidRuntime(24895):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208)
10-25 00:31:59.274: E/AndroidRuntime(24895):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
10-25 00:31:59.274: E/AndroidRuntime(24895):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
10-25 00:31:59.274: E/AndroidRuntime(24895):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
10-25 00:31:59.274: E/AndroidRuntime(24895): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-25 00:31:59.274: E/AndroidRuntime(24895):    at com.videotrafico.ReporteActivity$asyncreport.doInBackground(ReporteActivity.java:260)
10-25 00:31:59.274: E/AndroidRuntime(24895):    at com.videotrafico.ReporteActivity$asyncreport.doInBackground(ReporteActivity.java:1)
10-25 00:31:59.274: E/AndroidRuntime(24895):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
10-25 00:31:59.274: E/AndroidRuntime(24895):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
10-25 00:31:59.274: E/AndroidRuntime(24895):    ... 5 more
```

The line where it gives the error is this one:

```
file = new File(fileUri.getPath());
```

How can i override the app to die if the file is not setted up?

Thanks!

AsyncTask:

```
 class asyncreport extends AsyncTask< String, String, String > {

            String rep;
            String user;
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                //para el progress dialog
                pDialog = new ProgressDialog(ReporteActivity.this);
                pDialog.setMessage("Enviando reporte");
                pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                pDialog.setCancelable(false);
                pDialog.show();
            }

            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                //obtnemos usr y pass
                rep=params[0];
                user=params[1];
                File file = new File(fileUri.getPath());
                //enviamos y recibimos y analizamos los datos en segundo plano.
                if (loginstatus(rep, user, file)==true){                        
                    return "ok"; //login valido
                }else{          
                    return "err"; //login invalido                    
                }

            }


            /*Una vez terminado doInBackground segun lo que halla ocurrido 
            pasamos a la sig. activity
            o mostramos error*/
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

               pDialog.dismiss();//ocultamos progess dialog.
               Log.e("onPostExecute=",""+result);

               if (result.equals("ok")){
                   Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
                   startActivity(i);
                }else{
                    Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
                       startActivity(i);
                }

                                                        }

            }
```

Ok the problem was the `public Uri fileUri;`is now setted to `public Uri fileUri = Uri.parse("");`

But the app is not posting the data anyway!

this is the code por post:

```
try {
                  MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity();
                 Log.e("enviando", fileUri.getPath());
                  entity.addPart("reporte", new StringBody(reporte));
                  entity.addPart("usuarioID", new StringBody(user));
                  entity.addPart("archivo", new FileBody(file));
                  httppost.setEntity(entity);
                  HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                     e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                     e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Comment: SO why not you are using code to check null

Comment: Without seeing your AsyncTask this is hard to debug… but there is a  java.lang.NullPointerException in your doInBackground so you're probably missing a if/null check.

Comment: your fileUri object is null check whether it is initialized or not..

Comment: Thanks, the AsyncTask is posted now.

Comment: Where did you declared and initialized  fileUri?

Comment: At the top of the class like this: public Uri fileUri;

Comment: @DouglasRoos you have declared ok. but where have you initialized?

Comment: That's the problem, it's not being initialized until i capture an image or video, how can i initialize the Uri before?

Comment: :D if this is not initialized at the point, then what is the use of that here? Improve your logic or change... you can't do any thing with that until that will initialized..

Comment: Ok, i've initialized the Uri doing public Uri fileUri = Uri.parse(""); now the app don't die but is not posting the data either :S i suppose is because the last code i've added to the main post.

Comment: Initializing it for the sake of avoiding the null doesn't fix the faulty logic. Yes, it's not null, but it's empty and so it doesn't work. Why are you using the Uri of a file that DOESN'T exist in a task that is expecting data from that file?!

Comment: … if your FileUri is not populated/initialized with the real data, why are you firing an async task that expects that data?! Correctly initialize your file and THEN start our asynctask.

Comment: Ok, but the thing is that the data i sent not always will have a file, thats why i'm using the empty initialization. Or what is the best way to do it?

Comment: Now i see that it was a stupid question, sorry, i'm very tired, just adding an IF to the code was enough after initialize the Uri. Thanks to all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not initialized `fileUri` to a value,you could do this by passing the Uri to the AsyncTask using the constructor.

```
      public class asyncReport extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>
      {
          String user,rep
          String fileUri;

          public asyncReport(String fileUri)
          {
             this.fileUri=fileUri;
          }

         ...
      }
```

Also when you say `<input,progress,output>` as `<String,String,String>` you have to publish progress of your operation using a String.I recommend that you use `<String,Integer,String>` instead.In order to publish progress use:

```
      //In your doInBackground
        publishProgress(progress);//create and maintain a variable to do this

      //in your AsyncTask
      onProgressUpdate(int progress)       
      {
         setProgressPrecent(progress);
      }
```

You could also pass fileUri as one of the parameters to your doInBackground.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do a null check and proceed with your code and I guess that should do it.

```
if(fileUri!=null)
{
     file = new File(fileUri.getPath());
     // do all relevant part here. 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but if i do that the app dies anyway in the line of that if, it looks like the problem is with the fileUri, how can i set something to that? Just to override the app kepp dying?

Answer (score -2):

I suspect this is how you want to call your async task:

```
HttpTraitement task = new HttpTraitement(this);
task.execute("http://namedomain/test.php");
In order to do that, you must change your async task the following way:

public class HttpTraitement extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, HttpResponse> {

    private Context context;

    public HttpTraitement (Context context) 
    {
        this.context = context;     
    }

    @Override
    protected HttpResponse doInBackground(String... params) {
        HttpResponse response = null;
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(params[0]);

        try {
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            response = client.execute(httppost); 

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            Toast.makeText(this.context, "Caught ClientProtocolException", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Toast.makeText(this.context, "Caught IOException", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(this.context, "Exception", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();                  
        }

        return response;

    }

}
Please note that the method execute() must be called only once for each async task object. Thus if you want to call it for more than one URL, you must do this:

HttpTraitement task1 = new HttpTraitement(this);
task1.execute("http://namedomain/test1.php");
HttpTraitement task2 = new HttpTraitement(this);
task2.execute("http://namedomain/test2.php");
```